# AuthenticationFailedException in jmeter

Tags: email, smtp, jmeter

I am getting following error while trying to send email through smtp sampler in Jmeter

```
Response message: AuthenticationFailedException: authentication failed - wrong username / password!
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtNW
534-5.7.14 zdNvElUfbicxf3RFoInwGpHpfrQqFvceUdxA1pEgWYOZ65zRS0729Xl6Jq4lVffclz6gbm
534-5.7.14 GGK4g5szGoH_69A6eDIm0sPoOyAByyzvX5jpOJ2jerymlV5dj8afTQgCiPx8kQX-UnLC50
534-5.7.14 c0fDF2mbV22Qob5V5dDiIE9bT3dLobcGf4vzdmZ-92PszZV8BuZkR3Vr9SDz_AJQCFYpz5
534-5.7.14 WTonYPGTzcgcYfewuSMhA_mLNKWY> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 ir5sm24871302pbc.13 - gsmtp


Data used:
server : smtp.googlemail.com
port :587
```

Note : credentials i used are correct

how can i overcome this?

Comment: Did you check the link given above?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that `Use StartTLS` box is checked
2. Make sure you use full email address as username, i.e `johndoe@gmail.com`, not `johndoe`
3. Log into web version at least once and make sure that credentials are correct, account is not locked, 2-factor authentication is off, etc.

Known "good" configuration of the SMTP Request Sampler for Google Mail:

[image: JMeter SMTP Sampler]

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) guide for detailed instructions.